LinearOptimization fails to find minimum of mixed-integer problem
Consider the following setting:
    vi = {2.1046684005357883`, 0.14074069882048335`, 0.4558990785854712`, 0.3774090406082292`, 0.6248725928164722`, 0.14229042026452854`, 0.9060513624670112`, 1.8764469484898794`, 0.14081659595046414`, 0.48083110867545864`, 1.6567094543238614`};
    constr = {2.358305321058765` xs[1] + 2.513178822494303` xs[2] +  1.0965079471838233` xs[3] + 3.6447176790612925` xs[4] + 5.874814349219386` xs[8] + 3.624324460258949` xs[9] +   1.1090584835517485` xs[11] <= 1.1090584523414149`, xs[1] + xs[2] + xs[3] + xs[4] + xs[5] + xs[6] + xs[7] + xs[8] + xs[9] + xs[10] + xs[11] <= 5., 1. >= xs[1] >= 0., 1. >= xs[2] >= 0., 1. >= xs[3] >= 0., 1. >= xs[4] >= 0.,  1. >= xs[5] >= 0., 1. >= xs[6] >= 0., 1. >= xs[7] >= 0., 1. >= xs[8] >= 0., 1. >= xs[9] >= 0., 1. >= xs[10] >= 0., 1. >= xs[11] >= 0.};
    rankcounti = 11;
    xstable = Array[xs, rankcounti];

We try to solve the following minimization problem using LinearOptimization
    obj = -Sum[vi[[j]] xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}]

-2.10467 xs[1] - 0.140741 xs[2] - 0.455899 xs[3] - 0.377409 xs[4] - 
 0.624873 xs[5] - 0.14229 xs[6] - 0.906051 xs[7] - 1.87645 xs[8] - 
 0.140817 xs[9] - 0.480831 xs[10] - 1.65671 xs[11]

The set of constraints is non-empty as a trivial instance of all zeros satisfy it:
FindInstance[constr, xstable \[Element] Integers]

{{xs[1] -> 0, xs[2] -> 0, xs[3] -> 0, xs[4] -> 0, xs[5] -> 0, xs[6] -> 0, xs[7] -> 0, xs[8] -> 0, xs[9] -> 0, xs[10] -> 0,  xs[11] -> 0}}

However, LinearOptimization fails to find the minimum and produces the error that there are no points that satisfy constraints.
LinearOptimization[-Sum[vi[[j]] xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}], constr, xstable \[Element] Integers, Tolerance -> 10^(-20), WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]

LinearOptimization::nsolc: There are no points that satisfy the constraints.
{xs[1] -> Indeterminate, xs[2] -> Indeterminate, xs[3] -> Indeterminate, xs[4] -> Indeterminate, xs[5] -> Indeterminate, xs[6] -> Indeterminate, xs[7] -> Indeterminate, xs[8] -> Indeterminate, xs[9] -> Indeterminate, xs[10] -> Indeterminate, xs[11] -> Indeterminate}

The issue is that the coefficient in front of
    xs[11]  1.1090584835517485`

is only slightly larger than allowed by inequality
    <= 1.1090584523414149`

NMinimize is also of no help
    NMinimize[{-Sum[vi[[j]] xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}], constr}, xstable \[Element] 
    Integers, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
    NMinimize::nsol: There are no points that satisfy the constraints {2.35831 xs[1]+2.51318 xs[2]+1.09651 xs[3]+3.64472 xs[4]+5.87481 xs[8]+3.62432 xs[9]+1.10906 xs[11]<=1.10906,xs[1]+xs[2]+xs[3]+xs[4]+xs[5]+xs[6]+xs[7]+xs[8]+xs[9]+xs[10]+<<1>><=5.,1.>=xs[1]>=0.,1.>=xs[2]>=0.,1.>=xs[3]>=0.,1.>=xs[4]>=0.,1.>=xs[5]>=0.,1.>=xs[6]>=0.,1.>=xs[7]>=0.,1.>=xs[8]>=0.,<<3>>}.    

Your help and suggestions will be highly appreciated

Mathematica v12.2 gives a nontrivial solution for NMinimize[{-Sum[vi[[j]] xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}], constr},   xstable \[Element] Integers ]

Change constr to "single" inequalities:
vi = {2.1046684005357883`, 0.14074069882048335`,0.4558990785854712`,0.3774090406082292`,0.6248725928164722`, 0.14229042026452854`, 0.9060513624670112`,1.8764469484898794`,0.14081659595046414`, 0.48083110867545864`,1.6567094543238614`};
rankcounti = 11;
xstable = Array[xs, rankcounti];
constr = Join[{2.358305321058765` xs[1] + 2.513178822494303` xs[2] + 
         1.0965079471838233` xs[3] + 3.6447176790612925` xs[4] + 
         5.874814349219386` xs[8] + 3.624324460258949` xs[9] + 
         1.1090584835517485` xs[11] <= 1.1090584523414149`}, 
      Map[# >= 0 &, xstable], Map[1 >= # &, xstable]]

With modified integer constraints LinearOptimization evaluates
LinearOptimization[ -Sum[vi[[j]] xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}], constr ,Map[Element[# , Integers] &, xstable]  ]
(*{xs[1] -> 0, xs[2] -> 0, xs[3] -> 1, xs[4] -> 0, xs[5] -> 1,xs[6] -> 1,xs[7] -> 1, xs[8] -> 0, xs[9] -> 0, xs[10] -> 1,xs[11] -> 0}*)

Hope it helps!

I am sorry for a late reply. Your solution avoids the constraint that \sum x[j]<=5. If you insert this constraint Linear Optimization fails again.

@AlexeyKushnir You didn't mention this constraint \sum x[j]<=5 in your question

I did mention this constraint. See the first code: xs[1] + xs[2] + xs[3] + xs[4] + xs[5] + xs[6] + xs[7] + xs[8] + xs[9] + xs[10] + xs[11] <= 5

 constr = {2.358305321058765 xs[1] + 2.513178822494303 xs[2] +  1.0965079471838233 xs[3] + 3.6447176790612925 xs[4] + 5.874814349219386 xs[8] + 3.624324460258949 xs[9] +   1.1090584835517485 xs[11] <= 1.1090584523414149`, xs[1] + xs[2] + xs[3] + xs[4] + xs[5] + xs[6] + xs[7] + xs[8] + xs[9] + xs[10] + xs[11] <= 5., 1. >= xs[1] >= 0., 1. >= xs[2] >= 0., 1. >= xs[3] >= 0., 1. >= xs[4] >= 0.,  1. >= xs[5] >= 0., 1. >= xs[6] >= 0., 1. >= xs[7] >= 0., 1. >= xs[8] >= 0., 1. >= xs[9] >= 0., 1. >= xs[10] >= 0., 1. >= xs[11] >= 0.};'

@AlexeyKushnir My solution fullfills additional constraint Total[xs]<=5!

Let us now add this additional constraint (as I am solving many similar problems and I want to make sure that the solution satisfies the additional constraint.)
constr =
Join[{2.358305321058765  xs[1] + 2.513178822494303  xs[2] +
1.0965079471838233  xs[3] + 3.6447176790612925  xs[4] +
5.874814349219386  xs[8] + 3.624324460258949  xs[9] +
1.1090584835517485  xs[11] <= 1.1090584523414149},
Map[# >= 0 &, xstable],
Map[1 >= # &,
xstable], {xs[1] + xs[2] + xs[3] + xs[4] + xs[5] + xs[6] + xs[7] +
xs[8] + xs[9] + xs[10] + xs[11] <= 5.}] '

Then, LinearOptimization[ -Sum[vi[[j]] xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}], constr ,Map[Element[# , Integers] &, xstable]  ] returns '{xs[1] -> Indeterminate, xs[2] -> Indeterminate,
xs[3] -> Indeterminate, xs[4] -> Indeterminate,
xs[5] -> Indeterminate, xs[6] -> Indeterminate,
xs[7] -> Indeterminate, xs[8] -> Indeterminate,
xs[9] -> Indeterminate, xs[10] -> Indeterminate,
xs[11] -> Indeterminate} '
